# Socket IO flutter not connecting

Tags: node.js, flutter, express, dart, socket.io

I am facing an issue connecting my socket io flutter client to my nodejs socket io server.
I am aware of the compatibility issue between the node socket io package and the flutter socket io client package. Hence, I installed only compatible versions of dependencies on both ends.

i.e.,
for flutter

```yaml
socket_io_client: ^1.0.2
```

and for server side.

```json
{
   "socket.io": "^2.4.1",
}
```

I have also tried the latest dependencies but I am getting the same **timeout** message in my logs,
Initially, I thought it was my server's issue, but I checked the connection using postman and it works.

Below I am adding my implementations for both server and client side,

```js
const { socketGuard } = require('./middlewares/socketio.middleware');
let io;

module.exports = {

    init: (server) => {
        
        io = require("socket.io")(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

        io.use(async (socket, next) => {

            let result = await socketGuard(socket);

            if (result.isValid) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                next(new Error("Not authorized"));
            }

        });

        io.on("connection", (socket) => {

            console.log(`${socket.id} : connected`);

        });

        return io;
    },

    get: () => {


        if (!io) {


            throw new Error("Socket io not initialized");

        }

        return io;

    }

};
```

and for flutter, I have added the following lines in the init function,

```dart
    io.Socket socket = io.io("http://192.168.1.14:5000");

    socket.onConnect((data) {log("Hello world");});

    socket.onConnectError((data) {log(data);});

    socket.onError((data) {log(data);});

    socket.on("message", (data) {log(data);});
```

Comment: Did you mange to make it work? NodeJS side working fine. But flutter is not connecting nodejs socket.io!

Comment: Yes it's working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [socket_io client readme](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client)

`In Flutter env. not (Flutter Web env.) it only works with dart:io websocket, not with dart:html websocket or Ajax (XHR), so in this case you have to add setTransports(['websocket']) when creates the socket instance.`

Try adding an options `Map` when you initialize your `socket`.

This is just a different way of doing the same thing from the example in `pub.dev`.

```
io.Socket socket = io.io("http://192.168.1.14:5000", <String, dynamic>{
    "transports": ["websocket"],
});
```

On one of my projects I can confirm that it doesn't work without this being passed in.

Comment: If you don;t mind can elaborate why this happened

Comment: Actually my only mistake was that I tested with two implementation and in second implementation I must have done typo (websocket -> **websockets**), cause I believe I passed that argument before also, I am editing my implementation.